# How to animate AR Objects except rotate animation?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Can anyone tell me how to animate 3d objects in Augmented reality using Android studio?.. I know how to rotate an object but I don't know how to create other animations like shrinking, moving etc.. 
Can anyone suggest any tutorials or any other links to animate AR 3d objects using Android studio..

Comment: If you want to animate the actual 3D object, for example you have a humanoid 3D model and you want it to swing a sword, then you will need to add a skeleton and use a tool like Blender to get the 3D object to change its shape.  You cannot do this in Android studio.  If you want to resize the 3D model or move the placement of the 3D object from one location to anther and not actually have the model change shapes that is a different topic.

Comment: Thank you for your information.. I know you are telling about Model animation. Is there any other way to animate 3D model using property animation like rotation.

Comment: Are you using ARCore?

Comment: Yes.. I am using ARCore..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/animation